# Disable the buttons inside div using ng-disabled

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a div which has many buttons and a main button. I want to disable whole div once main button is clicked. Something like following

```
<body ng-app>
    <div ng-disabled="disableDiv">
      <input type="button" value="btn1" >
      <input type="button" value="btn2" >
      <input type="button" value="btn3" >
      <input type="button" value="Main Button" ng-click="disableDiv=true">
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of options include:

**Using fieldset instead of div:**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app='app'>
    <fieldset ng-disabled="disableDiv">
      <input type="button" value="btn1" >
      <input type="button" value="btn2" >
      <input type="button" value="btn3" >
      <input type="button" value="Main Button" ng-click="disableDiv=true">
    </fieldset >
</body>
```

**Manually disabling:**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.disable = function(evt) {
    angular.element(evt.target.parentNode).children().attr('disabled', true);
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app='app' ng-controller="myController">
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="btn1" >
      <input type="button" value="btn2" >
      <input type="button" value="btn3" >
      <input type="button" value="Main Button" ng-click="disable($event)">
    </div>
</body>
```

**ng-disabled on each element**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app='app'>
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="btn1" ng-disabled="disableDiv">
    <input type="button" value="btn2" ng-disabled="disableDiv">
    <input type="button" value="btn3" ng-disabled="disableDiv">
    <input type="button" value="Main Button" ng-disabled="disableDiv" ng-click="disableDiv=true">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a function in the controller and set the `disabled` attribute to each button:

**js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.btnDisabled = false;

  $scope.disableDiv = function() {
   $scope.btnDisabled = true;
  }

});
```

**html**

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div>
    <input type="button" value="btn1" ng-disabled="btnDisabled">
    <input type="button" value="btn2" ng-disabled="btnDisabled">
    <input type="button" value="btn3" ng-disabled="btnDisabled">
    <input type="button" value="Main Button" ng-click="disableDiv()" ng-disabled="btnDisabled">
  </div>
</body>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IdfnJ6j4z1T8uaOc5Vne?p=info)

Comment: For this i don't need controller to do that. I just need whole div, because div also contains other inputs like anchor tag, input text etc

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like this:

```
<body ng-app>
    <div ng-hide="disableDiv">
        <input type="button" value="btn1" >
        <input type="button" value="btn2" >
        <input type="button" value="btn3" >
        <input type="button" value="Main Button" ng-click="disableDiv=true">
    </div>
</body>
```

The [ng-hide](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) directive will hide the element when its value is true.

Comment: No i want to disable the buttons not hide it.

Answer (score 0):

ng-disabled works only on HTML input elements. The div element has no “disabled” attribute, that’s why it fails.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled#usage